# Node.js: Not able to extract querystring value

Tags: javascript, node.js

With node.js

Code:

```
 var querystring = require('querystring');
 ...
 console.log("Incoming: ", event);
 var output = querystring.parse(event);
 console.log("Key 1 value is: ", output.key1);
```

Output:

```
Incoming:  { key3: 'value 3', key2: 'value 2', key1: 'value 3' }
Key 1 value is:  undefined
```

*Why is the Key1 value printed as undefined (although incoming event is printed correctly just before that)?*

Comment: `event` has already been parsed - if it were a querystring it would look like `key1=value3&key2=value2&key3=value1`.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `event` object isn't a querystring, so there isn't anything to parse in this case.

`querystring` is for parsing raw HTTP query strings:

```
var qs = require('querystring');
var parsed = qs.parse("key1=value3&key2=value2&key3=value1");
// { key1: 'value3', key2: 'value2', key3: 'value1' }
```

Comment: Thanks @joews > event.key1 gives me the desired result.